# Where did the Big Bang happen?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang

Does the Big Bang theory directly imply that there is a much larger structure in which our universe is embedded? If this is not true then where did the Big Bang happen? Where did the material before the Bang exist?

Comment: It happened **everywhere**! See this very good answer that might change your thoughts of Big Bang and universe expansion a bit:  [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: @Steeven I understood the reasoning in the answer. But the answer said that the universe is infinite. But what if the universe has a closed structure?Then the universe should be finite right?

Comment: I can't answer to what would be the case, if the universe was different than it is. Not my expertise area anyways, so I'm afraid I'm not the right person to ask. Rather open a new question, if you have one.